# Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Key shortcut on Surfacebook?

Tags: intel-graphics, microsoft-surface

I find it very helpful for graphics programs to turn my surface book on its side like a book, and turn the screen to portrait mode. Unfortunately, even though this is the first time I would find the CTRL+ALT+LEFT ARROW hot key helpful, it doesn't seem to be available. It would be really nice if I could quickly switch between portrait and landscape.

Currently my only workaround is to manually go into the display settings and change the orientation manually.

Is there a command line utility for Intel graphics drivers that I could link an Autohotkey script to or something like that so I can change the orientation more quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You can download this utility called Display:

http://noeld.com/programs.asp#Display

And invoke it by creating shortcuts like so (adjust accordingly for the location to which you extract the executable):

**C:\Display.exe /rotate:0**

**C:\Display.exe /rotate:90**

You can pin these shortcuts to your Taskbar, or - if you prefer to use key commands - right-click on each shortcut, choose Properties, switch to the Shortcut tab, and assign a unique keyboard shortcut by clicking the Shortcut key box and then press the keys that you would like to assign.